# Save Arabic text into MySQL database 

Tags: mysql

I have this Arabic text: `الخط الكوفي`. When I try to save it in a MySQL database it doesn't save.

Is there any way to save it as the original text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your MySQL instance and tables are set to take UTF-8, not latin1.

Section [9.1 of the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset.html) covers this.

Answer (score 3):

I'd take a look at the mysql docs for [Character Sets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-charsets.html). The default character set `latin1` most likely doesn't handle the characters you're trying to use. You'll have to switch your tables over to UTF-8 if you want to store that properly.