# PhpMyEdit displaying foreign languages as?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using [PhpMyEdit](http://www.phpmyedit.org/) and it is working fine and brilliant. The only thing is when displaying the arabic characters, it is showing as ???? ??. I only have one column which contains arabic text but very important to customer.

From reading and previously experimenting (with successful outcomes) I know I use `mysql_query("set characer set cp1256");`

 
after the mysql connect to ensure the arabic is supported. Also the table's collation was set as utf unicode.  it worked when displaying with simple sql in php.

Any idea what I can do to solve this?
I've also tried editing

> phpMyEdit.class.php

but with no luck...
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I just drilled deeper into the API code, and found that I have to add this at connect function:

```
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

inside the phpclass.php file. This made it work. I also re-constructed the table to make all fields utf8. now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

This question is an instance of : [Save Arabic text into MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152036/save-arabic-contain-into-mysql-database)

But try this :

When creating a table use default character set as utf-8

I show you how :

```
CREATE TABLE arabic_cont (
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
arabic_data text
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did that and mentioned it in the question. The problem is with PHPMyEdit

Answer (score 0):

sys_debug's answer works in Drupal 7.29. 
Add the line:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

within `function connect()` before `return true;` in phpMyEdit.class.php for displaying non-English text.