# insert mixed arabic and english text in mysql in same field

Tags: jquery, mysql

When I insert mixed Arabic and English text (jquery code) in MySQL in same field MySQL it shows only from start English character to start beginning Arabic language when retrieving data and then stops.

```
  must :  if(rt=="0"){alert("لم يتم ادخال المادة حاول مجددا "); }

  result :  if(rt=="0"){alert("Ù
```

Comment: Set all to **UTF-8** (Database, Website, Headers,..)

Comment: might be an issue of encoding in mysql... have a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152036/save-arabic-text-into-mysql-database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152036/save-arabic-text-into-mysql-database)

Comment: though it would also be nice to see what you're doing to get the output... is it already stored correctly in the db at all?

Answer (score 0):

you have to set everything to UTF-8

- database
- your editor where you write code
- headers

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  ```